# How to change postgresql requiring "other" permission to import csv files

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, psycopg2

I have recently changed to ubuntu from windows and am having difficulty with the permissions on my postgresql database which I am trying to recreate.

My problem is as follows:
I have a script which imports csv files into the postgresql database.
The data is located in multiple csv files and I am using psycopg2 to handle the importing with a wrapper.

However, there is an issue with user permissions.

To run the file I need to manually change the permissions of each csv file (can do in bulk) so that the "other" permissions are set to read and write.

Is this some issue with how I have set up the database initially? And if so, how can I rectify it.

To clarify:

> > > I wish to know how to change my database settings to not require a manual permissions change to the "other" settings in order to allow import.

Scripts added by request

```
import psycopg2 as psy
import sys

conn = psy.connect("dbname = 'name' host='localhost' user = 'postgres' password ='password')
curs = conn.cursor()
tablename = 'tabname'
filename  = 'filename'

Input = "COPY %s FROM %s WITH CSV HEADER" % (tablename, filename)
curs.copy_expert(Input, sys.stdin)

conn.commit()
curs.close()
conn.close()
```

This then has a wrapper around it to simply move between files and tables

I know it works, however, it requires that I manually change the permissions of the csv files so that "others" may read and write them.

I wish to know why this is the case

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but permissions on CSV files (external to the database) have nothing to do with the setup of the database.

Comment: That was my understanding as well, I believe it could possibly be due to the user which the database is using. In this case, the 'postgres' user.

Comment: So you're are using custom Python scripts to read the CSV files, connect to the DB and import the data? Check your scripts or at least paste them here!

Comment: Hi Milen, I've added the script which is being used as requested. To clarify, I know it works to import the file to the database, however it requires me to manually adjust the file permissions of the csv files so that 'others' may read and write them. This occurs when calling the script via sudo python script.py as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix systems enforce filesystem permissions. No user process can access data owned by another user, unless the permissions on the data *allow* the access. The only user not subjected to these constraints is the `root` account; but because `root` is *incredibly* powerful, you should not run any processes as `root` unless it is absolutely necessary.

There are several options, depending upon how restrictive you want to keep the data:

- You can make the files owned by the `postgres` user. This is a bit blunt-force and might become annoying if you must regularly work with the CSV files as a user, as well. It's about the same as your current approach *but* requires that `root` do the `chown(1)` calls. (You cannot give away files on modern systems.)

  This is akin to `find /path/to/top -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chown postgres`
- You can make a new group; add the group to the list of supplementary groups that PostgreSQL runs as, make that group the group owner of the files, and make sure that group has read permissions on these files. This might be pretty simple, especially if all the files live in one directory or one hierarchy. (The BSD groups behavior can set the group ownership of a file in a clever way.)

  This approach takes a few steps:

  - use `groupadd(8)` or a similar command to add the group.
  - modify the PostgreSQL configuration to add the group to the supplementary groups list.
  - `find /path/to/top -print0 | xargs -0 chgrp group_name`
  - If you want to use BSD groups:

    - read the `mount(8)` manpage's section on the `bsdgroups` `mount(8)` option.
    - add the `bsdgroups` mount option to your `/etc/fstab` file as needed.
    - remount the filesystem to include the `bsdgroups` mount option: `mount -oremount,bsdgroups /path/to/mount/point`
    - set the `setgid` bit on your directories: `find /path/to/top -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod g+s`

- You can grant read access to the files to *every* user on the system. This requires trusting every process on the computer with the data -- which might not be a good decision if the machine hosts unrelated services, such as web, ftp, mail, database services for unrelated clients or systems, etc.

  You may be able to modify the `umask(2)` setting of the program that *creates* the CSV files. This mask is applied when files are created and most programs do not try to over-ride the `umask(2)` setting. Most shells make it easy to change the `umask(2)` for itself and all child processes -- try running `umask 0022` in the shell that you use to create the CSV files, and see what that does. (It turns off the `write` permission for group and other. You won't need the `write` permission unless PostgreSQL also updates those files, but you only said you needed to import them.)

Try to pick the solution that is both easiest *and* respects the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) -- grant as little permission as necessary to each service on a system to restrict the potential consequences of insecure programs or configurations.

Comment: I should mention in passing that even `root` is not necessarily all-powerful: because it is too powerful, the POSIX.1e _draft capabilities_ have been implemented on Linux; the specific capabilities `root` uses to bypass the file discretionary access control lists are `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE`, `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH`, `CAP_FOWNER`. There are dozens of these capabilities, and each one describes some portion of `root`'s power. See `capabilities(7)` for full details.

Comment: I think I understand, so to clarify: the files are owned by me, I am trying to access them with postgres which does not have permission to do so. To rectify the issue I can add postgres to a group which "owns" the files or add the ability to read and write them to everyone?

Comment: Exactly; and you have several options for how to change the group ownership of the files -- you can either change it when you need it or you can go down the slightly complicated BSD groups approach to have the groups magically set correctly.

Comment: Thank you Sarnold, I think I'm beginning to understand the conceptual difference compared to a Windows system. I've accepted your answer as correct

Comment: Glad to help -- it took me a few years to get the hang of the idea of separate users on the system, but when they are properly used, they can solve an impressive number of problems.

Comment: I suppose this is what I get for wanting a more customizable system with ubuntu compared to windows right. Freedom, at a cost. Your experience is very much appreciated.

Comment: The difference to Windows isn't really that big. Windows enforces the similar file system access privileges. The only difference is that (unfortunately) the default for most directories is "everyone full access" in Windows

Answer (score 2):

A workaround - replace of the [`copy_expert`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) with [`copy_from`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) as in:

```
f = open(filename)
curs.copy_from(f, tablename, ...)
```

This way your script will be reading the CSV files and not the server process so no need to tweak permissions.

Comment: @Dantes: strongly consider accepting this answer instead of mine -- it is superb.